# Frobenius coin problem, 5 and 9

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction

I am hoping to get some help with two problems related to Forbenius coin problems.

$A)$ A fictional government has decided to issue currency in only $5$ and $9$ value denominations.  Prove that there is a largest value that the people of this country cannot pay with these denominations.  What is this value?

I have researched this and it seems to be a Frobenius coin problem.  I have also found that since $5$ and $9$ are relatively prime, the largest value that cannot be paid for with $5$ and $9$ denominations is $(5 \cdot 9)-5-9$ or $31.$  I am not sure where to start when proving that there is a largest number.  Obviously any number that can be paid for with $5$ and $9$ will fall into the linear combination $5a + 9b$ where $a$ and $b$ are non-negative integers, but I am not sure where to go from here.  Any help would be great.

$B)$ Using induction, prove that every amount greater than the value found in $A (31)$ is can be paid for using $5$ and $9$ value denominations.

Obviously the base case here is $n=~32$, which works because $32 = 1 \cdot 5+3\cdot 9$.  But I am unsure how to structure the predicate such that I can prove the inductive step. Again any hints here would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ It is possible to pay the amounts $32 = 27 + 5$, $33 = 18 + 15$, $34 = 9 + 25$, $35 = 7 \cdot 5$ and $36 = 4 \cdot 9$. You should use this as the base case to prove with induction that any amount $N \geq 32$ can be paid. It then immediately follows that there is a largest value that cannot be paid.