# How many natural numbers can't be written as 5p+7q, where p and q are natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, diophantine-equations, natural-numbers

If $A = \{5p+7q|p,q \in \mathbb{N}\}$, determine $|\mathbb{N} \setminus A|$.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Look up the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#:~:text=The%20coin%20problem%20(also%20referred,only%20coins%20of%20specified%20denominations.)  One on this site is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563401/frobenius-coin-problem-5-and-9)

Comment: On this site you are expected to give a bit more context on what  you have tried and what you can use. It is not just a site for uploading your homework.

Comment: It's also called the chicken mcnugget theorem :)

Comment: Try writing 5p+7q mod5, multiples of 7 span all of mod5

Comment: That's what I tried. I just want someone to confirm if the answer is 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two prime numbers p,q the set which can not be represented as pa+qb with $a,b \in N$ is finite. There is a maximal non-representable number which is pq-p-q. This is known as the Frobenius number. There is a formula for the number of non-representable numbers $\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{2}$.

Refs:

Ramírez-Alfonsín, J. L. The Diophantine Frobenius Problem. Oxford, England: Oxford University Press, 2005.

Comment: Thank you so much! My answer was also 12 , but I wasn't sure, because the solution from my book says it's 13.

Comment: You might be expected to prove the theorem for your class, or maybe just apply the formula. In the future when you ask it is good to give a little more context plus what you have tried.

Comment: Where does these numbers came from? Can you at least cite some book or something.